# NetSuite - Get Transaction Type using suite script API

Tags: netsuite

How to get Transaction Type using suite script API? Based on the fetched value want to perform logic.  Is it possible to fetch transaction type?

```
   function afterSubmit(type) {
            if (type == 'create' || type == 'edit') {
                //how to get transaction type(transType) so that I can use in the condition???
                if (transType == 'SalesOrd') {

                    var toemail = nlapiLookupField('customer',
                            nlapiGetFieldValue('customer'), 'email');
                    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'ToEmail', toemail);
                    var emailSubject = 'Hello World';
                    var emailBody = 'Hello World Message';
                    var fromId = -5;
                    nlapiSendEmail(fromId, toemail,
                            emailSubject, emailBody, null, null, null, null);

                }// if
                else

                if (transType == PurchOrd) {
                    var toemail = nlapiLookupField('customer',
                            nlapiGetFieldValue('customer'), 'email');
                    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'ToEmail', toemail);
                    var emailSubject = 'Hello World';
                    var emailBody = 'Hello World Message';
                    var fromId = -5;
                    nlapiSendEmail(fromId, toemail,
                            emailSubject, emailBody, null, null, null, null);

                }
            }// end

    }
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are dozens of ways probably.  Here are a few:

In SS1:

```
var myRecordType = nlapiGetRecordType(); //gives you the internal id ie: 'salesorder' etc
```

or

```
var myRecord = nlapiGetNewRecord();
var myRecordType = myRecord.getFieldValue('type') //as above
```

In SS2:

```
var myRecord = context.newRecord;
var myRecordType = myRecord.type; //value from the record.Type "enum" ie: SALES_ORDER
```